# RSA question for public exponent is an even number but not 2, and not big

Tags: rsa

While Public exponent is an even number which means Can't get the d in normal way since gcd(e, phi) won't be 1, and in this case only used one prime number for N (multiple uses for one prime number)
What is the idea of getting the m,could p = 3 mod 4 be helpful?
Thank you for any idea.

Comment: 'Only used one prime number for N'; are you saying N is prime?

Comment: I meant N = p*p, I know when N is prime phi is simply N-1 if I remember correctly. But thanks for correcting I should make my words clearly.

Comment: $e = 2$ is used in the Rabin signature scheme ( first true signature scheme). While some people also defined Rabin's cryptosystem, Rabin was not defined.

Comment: I have look it up, but in my case the e is actually not 2 so i think it works slightly different? but thanks for the comment. (and nice to know the information about the Rabin part, funny lol

Answer (score 2):

I'll address the case $e=2$; if $\gcd(e, \phi(n)) = 2$, then this is sufficient (as it would suffice to find the squareroot of $c$ (the ciphertext), and then take the $e/2$th root of that.

So, we're given $c$ and want to find the values $m$ s.t. $m^2 = c \pmod {p^2}$.

We start by finding the values $m'$ s.t. $m'^2 = c \pmod p$; this is a modular squareroot, and there are known algorithms for it.  The easiest applies if $p \equiv 3 \pmod 4$; in that case, $m' = \pm c^{(p+1)/4} \bmod p$.  The $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ case is also doable, but is more work.

Given those values, we convert those into values modulo $p^2$.  That turns out to be even easier, because if we have $m = m' + xp$ (and $m$ will always be equivalent to one of the $m'$ values modulo $p$), then we have:

$$m^2 = (m' + xp)^2 = m'^2 + 2m'xp = c \pmod {p^2}$$

And, since $c-m'^2$ is a multiple of $p$, we can reduce this to:

$2m'x = (c - m'^2)/p \pmod p$, or $x = (2m')^{-1} (c - m'^2)/p \pmod p$

And, $m = m' + px$ gives you the values of $m$ (and remember, there are two possible values of $m'$ and hence two possible values of $m$).

---

Also note that, because we managed to do with without any private information, this doesn't work as 'public key encryption'

Comment: So if the public exponent is 2^a int (not 1), will that change the idea of this? And I do have a question for gcd(e, phi), What does gcd(e, phi) effects like in this case it is 2 but how if in other cases it is 4 or 8 or something is that matter at all? Sorry too many questions...

Comment: @dlfls: if it is 4 or 8, just run the above procedure 2 or 3 times...